# Corrupt Builds with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Recently i have been experiencing more and more corrupt builds.
For instance when i access

```
 npc[4]
```

it accesses

```
 npc[3].
```

Or instead of

```
details->Hp
```

it returns

```
details->Energy.
```

Problem magically fixes itself when i rebuild. (after i spent hours trying to find the non-existing bug of course)

This is getting more frequent while my project gets bigger and bigger.
Why does something like this occurs? 
How can i avoid it?

I hope i made myself clear.

thank you.

Comment: I would assume you have a bug somewhere ;)

Comment: If it fixes itself when you rebuild, when does it break itself?

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer the question.  What version of Visual Studio?  Is this a multi-project solution?  Are you sure that all of the project and library dependencies are configured correctly?  Are you sure that all of your projects and source files are built with the same options?  From your description, it sounds like you are violating the one-definition rule (ODR) because something isn't being rebuilt as required.

Comment: visual studio 8. i appears out of nowhere. i wasnt even editting the problamatic part. game uses a lot of static and dynamic libraries, but corruptions occur in my own code.

Comment: I often find discontinuities develop between what the debugger says, and what the code actually does, over protracted edit + partial builds: I myself do a full build at the end of the day. Beyond that recommendation, I can't be of much more assistance.

Comment: Try to turn off "Edit and Continue" feature

Comment: I believe this is a problem with pre-compiled headers. When I developed in Visual Studio, I found that this type of decay goes away when NOT using pre-compiled headers. Of course, your build will take longer without pch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the comments. i have found the problem.
precompiled headers. they get corrupted after a while and cause unintended behaviors.
there doesn't seem to me solution at the moment since I'm forced to use pchs.

Comment: AFAIK if you edit a header whic get's included into precompiled header then you have to recompile PCH manualy :D if you don't you got errors

Comment: most of the time it doesn't care. but apparently not all the time.